# Capture non-equality of values in two elements of a list

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, error-handling

I want to create `if()` conditions to capture when values in the `x` element of a `list()` are not all the same **OR** values in the `y` element of a `list()` are not all the same **OR** both situations together.

For concreteness, I have provided 4 lists with the expected warnings below.

Is this possible in R?

```
A = list(x = c(1,1,1,1), y = c(2,4,3,3)) # Expect warning that says `y` is bad!

B = list(x = c(1,2,1,1), y = c(3,3,3,3)) # Expect warning that says `x` is bad!

C = list(x = c(1,2,1,1), y = c(3,2,3,3)) # Expect warning that says `x` and `y` are bad!

D = list(x = c(1,1,1,1), y = c(3,3,3,3)) # Expect no warning !
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could create a condition to check the `length` of `unique` elements in each of the elements in the `list`

```
f1 <- function(lst_obj) {
      v1 <- sapply(lst_obj, function(x) length(unique(x)))
      i1 <- names(which(v1 != 1))
      if(length(i1) == 1) {
          warning(paste(i1, " is bad!"))
       } else if(length(i1) > 1) {
           warning(paste(i1, collapse = ' and '), " are bad!")
       } 
    
}

f1(A)
#Warning message:
#In f1(A) : y is bad!

f1(B)
#Warning message:
#In f1(B) : x is bad!

f1(C)
#Warning message:
#In f1(C) : x and y are bad!
f1(D)
```

Comment: Arun, [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66935495/7223434) is the question you asked me to ask. Thank you.

Comment: Very kind of you.