# Creating a logic to capture two types of non-equality in a list with two elements

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, error-handling

I want to efficiently merge two logics into one logic to capture two types of mismatches in a `list` with two elements of the same length.

**First,** capturing when `0` values in one element of a `list()` are NOT `0` for the corresponding positions in the second element of the same `list()`.

For example, in `A` list, the first two values of `x` are `0`, but the first two values of `y` are NOT `0`. So, I want to catch this as an error (`stop`).

However, in `B` list, the first three values of `x` are `0`, and the first three values of `y` are `0` as well. So, I want to catch this as a (`warning`).

*A solution was kindly suggested to me [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66912754/7223434).*

**Second,** capturing when values in the `x` element of a `list()` are not all the same **OR** values in the `y` element of a `list()` are not all the same **OR** both situations together. These are shown in lists `A1`, `B1` & `C1`.

*A solution was kindly suggested to me [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66926306/7223434).*

It seems these two logics overlap to some extent. For example, list `A` is considered `error` using the first logic AND the second logic.

**Question:** Can we create one solution to merge [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66912754/7223434) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66926306/7223434) into one function?

```
# First logic examples:
( A = list(x = c(0,0,2,2), y = c(3,3,1,1)) ) # Expect error
( B = list(x = c(0,0,1,1), y = c(0,0,1,1)) ) # Expect warning
( C = list(x = c(0,1,1,0), y = c(2,1,0,0)) ) # Expect error


# Second logic examples:
( A1 = list(x = c(1,1,1,1), y = c(2,4,3,3)) ) # Expect error that says `y` is bad!
( B1 = list(x = c(1,2,1,1), y = c(3,3,3,3)) ) # Expect error that says `x` is bad!
( C1 = list(x = c(1,2,1,1), y = c(3,2,3,3)) ) # Expect error that says `x` and `y` are bad!

( D = list(x = c(1,1,1,1), y = c(3,3,3,3) ) # Expect FINE !
```

Comment: In your example, 'A' . How would you prioritize which error to return i..e A first and second element have two unique values.  So, it can be an error as showed in A1

Comment: Is the error preference more towards checking 0 and then check for the unique or is it viceversa

Comment: Yes, I understand that, so, now the error in 'A' is both.  which one should be returned as error

Comment: So, the 0 error is not important?

Comment: let say you have `B2 <- list(x = c(0, 0, 1, 2), y = c(0, 0, 1, 1))` does it return both warning and error? warning because there are 0s not exculsive, error because there are more than one unique element in both x and y

Comment: That part is confusing.  Even your 'B' should return both warning and error because there are no exclusive 0 and because there are two elements 0 and 1 which qualify for the error in second function

Comment: i.e.  x and y are both bad because they have both 0 and 1 as unique elements

Comment: Inorder to differentiate the different warning/error.  May be you cchange the "this is a warning" to "this is a zero warning" and "this is a zero error"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear about the order of execution of the warning/error.  In the below function, the `if` condition first checks if there are `any` 0s in the data and if it finds an error/warning, it reports and the `else` would be the case where there are no zeros, and then it will check for the `length` of `unique` elements and report the warning/error

```
check <- function(l){
  df <- as.data.frame(l)
  if(any(df == 0)){
    if(!any(rowSums(df == 0) == 1) ){
      warning("this is a warning")
    } else {
      stop("this is an error")
    }
  } else{
      v1 <- sapply(l, function(x) length(unique(x)))
      i1 <- names(which(v1 != 1))
      if(length(i1) == 1) {
          warning(paste(i1, " is bad!"))
       } else if(length(i1) > 1) {
           warning(paste(i1, collapse = ' and '), " are bad!")
       } 
  
    }
  }
```

-testing

```
check(A)
#Error in check(A) : this is an error
check(B)
#Warning message:
#In check(B) : this is a warning
check(C)
#Error in check(C) : this is an error
check(A1)
#Warning message:
#In check(A1) : y  is bad!
check(B1)
#Warning message:
#In check(B1) : x  is bad!
check(C1)
#Warning message:
#In check(C1) : x and y are bad!
check(D)
```

Comment: @rnorouzian sorry, I was away.   it seems to have a solution there.